# Date Range in Java

Tags: java

I have a `Date`. Now I want to calculate that the age of from that will be 2-12yrs if condition is true otherwise the age should be between 0-2 yrs. So how could we can calculate whether the age lies between 2-12 or 0-2 from a given date.

I have done something but I am confused how could I proceed.

```
public class Test {
  public static void main(String args[]) throws ParseException {
    String string = "29/07/13";
    Date oneWayTripDate = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM d, yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH).parse(string);
    String myFormat = "dd/MM/yy"; //In which you need put here
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(myFormat, Locale.US);       
  }
}
```

Then condition will be some thing like this

```
for child age should be between 2-12 (So from Current Date will calulate to  12 yrs .if the date given lies between 2-12yrs then it is true otherwise false) 
for infant age should be between 0-12 (So from Current Date will calulate to  2 yrs .if the date given lies between 0-2yrs then it is true otherwise false)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to find age you need two date values. You can try something like this

```
    DateFormat df=new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yy");
    Date birthDay=df.parse("29/07/13");
    Date currentDay=new Date();
    Calendar cal1=Calendar.getInstance();
    Calendar cal2=Calendar.getInstance();
    cal1.setTime(birthDay);
    cal2.setTime(currentDay);
    int years=cal2.get(Calendar.YEAR)-cal1.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    if(3>years){
        System.out.println("Infant");
    }else if(years<13){
        System.out.println("Child");
    } else{
        System.out.println("adult");
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use Joda Time [Period](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/Period.html)  ([Docs](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/key_period.html))

```
Date tripDate;
Date dob;
Period period = new Period(dob, tripDate, PeriodType. YearMonthDay);
int years = period.getYears();
if(years < 3) {
    // 0 - 2
} else if(years < 13) {
    // 2 - 12
} else {
    // adult
}
```

Comment: basically i have to check the child and infant age lies between 2-12yrs and 0-2 yrs simultaneously

Comment: I'm very sorry, I'm quite confused about what you mean. Any chance you could be more clear about what you're trying to do? (And perhaps edit the Q to be clearer?)

Comment: Ok, I've read that, but I still don't understand how my answer is not what you're looking for ....